# String is null after passing between two acitivites

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass String to another activity using `putExtra` method, but second activity shows this String as null. The "names" array is array of Strings and `globalMonth` is variable which is being set by `datepicker`.

Activity 1 code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("zodiacName",names[globalMonth]);
myIntent.putExtra("monthOfYear", globalMonth);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Activity 2 code:

```
String zodiacName=intent.getStringExtra("zodiacName");
myText.setText(""+zodiacName+"");
```

`TextView myText` is displaying `null`.

Comment: Please post some code that or where you initializing intent.

Comment: is names[globalMonth] really not null ?

Comment: are you getting "monthOfYear" also null ?

Comment: Yes, it is not null

Comment: monthOfYear is passed correctly

Comment: post all of you method where you get your extras (onCreate ?)

Comment: I'm getting extras in onCreate method, there is just Intent intent = getIntent() ; and the code above. I would like to pass the code, but I'm not on my PC right now

Comment: is names[globalMonth] a string ? use only getExtra to get the value

Comment: Yes, it is a string. I'll try it as soon as I get to PC

Comment: You have to check and debug app here
myIntent.putExtra("zodiacName",names[globalMonth]);
it's going null or not

Comment: `names[globalMonth]` sounds null to me

Comment: `intent.getStringExtra("zodiacName");` the intent variable, how do you get it?

Comment: I tried to pass the same value twice, and I get the first value correctly a second is null